Flickering Issue with Text Opacity Animation in Custom Flow /Stack /Animated Builder Component
I'm working on a Flutter component that animates the opacity between two pieces of text data using a Flow widget. I want to animate the fading effect between previousData and newData strings smoothly, but I'm experiencing a flickering issue whenever newData changes.
Here's the simplified code:

class FadingMarkdownComponent extends StatefulWidget {
  final String newData;
  final String previousData;

  const FadingMarkdownComponent(
      {super.key, required this.newData, required this.previousData});

  @override
  State<FadingMarkdownComponent> createState() =>
      _FadingMarkdownComponentState();
}

class _FadingMarkdownComponentState extends State<FadingMarkdownComponent>
    with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  // String _previousText = '';
  late final AnimationController _controller = AnimationController(
      vsync: this, duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 2000));

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller.reset();
    _controller.forward();
  }

  @override
  void didUpdateWidget(covariant FadingMarkdownComponent oldWidget) {

    super.didUpdateWidget(oldWidget);
    if (oldWidget.newData != widget.newData ||
        oldWidget.previousData != widget.previousData) {
      _controller.reset();
      _controller.forward();
    }
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    //Flow will handle RepaintBoundary.wrapAll
    return Flow(
      delegate: FlowOpacity(repaint: _controller),
      clipBehavior: Clip.none,
      children: [
        IgnorePointer(
          key: UniqueKey(),
          child: Text( widget.previousData),
        ),
        Text(key: UniqueKey(), widget.newData),
      ],
    );
  }
}

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class FlowOpacity extends FlowDelegate {
  final Animation<double> repaint;
  FlowOpacity({required this.repaint}) : super(repaint: repaint);
  @override
  void paintChildren(FlowPaintingContext context) {
    var forwardOpacity = repaint.value;
    var reverseOpacity =
        ReverseAnimation(repaint).value; // or just 1.0 - forwardOpacity

    context.paintChild(0,
        // transform: Matrix4.identity(), //by default
        opacity: reverseOpacity);
    context.paintChild(1,
        // transform: Matrix4.identity(), //by default
        opacity: forwardOpacity);
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(FlowOpacity oldDelegate) {
    return false; //or
    // return repaint.value != oldDelegate.repaint.value;
  }
}

Issue Description:
Every time newData changes, it triggers an animation from _controller, but I'm experiencing flickering on every text change, rather than a smooth opacity transition.
For More Info Check this link For Videos:
Issue Link
Expected Outcome:
A smooth fade animation between previousData and newData without flickering or Say Flickering.
Expected Outcome
A smooth fade animation between previousData and newData without flickering.
